# Libgdx intellij Black screen application when run

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I manage to set up libgdx in intellij idea 12 using this tutorial http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx but im not sure wthat is wrong when i run the desktop applcation it looks like this. [image]

I was expecting for an image of libgdx would appear just like the tutorial on [official libgdx website](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html). And for the intelliJ part of tutorial i link the desktop to asset folder of android. As you can see on the image below is the asset folder of android module which contain the image of libgdx.

[image]

I follow the Alternative 2 in the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IntelliJIDEALibgdx).

Here is the code:

DesktopStarter class - Desktop Module:

```
public class DesktopStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "Title";
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 480;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyLibgdxGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

MyLibgdxGameAndroidStarter class - Android Module:

```
public class MyLibgdxGameAndroidStarter extends AndroidApplication
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;
        cfg.useWakelock = true;
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        initialize(new MyLibgdxGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

MyLibgdxGame class - Main Module:

```
public class MyLibgdxGame extends Game {
    @Override
    public void create() {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Download the project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?zbevs7gyj0v52u8)

Anyone knows what went wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you followed all of the steps correctly? It'd be nice if you could provide some code or your specific run configurations. Chances are there was a typo somewhere.

Comment: Yes im pretty sure.. OK ill edit my post

Comment: You should zip and share the entire project so others can download and review it to verify that you've followed the tutorial correctly.

Comment: @CrazyCoder i edited my post. YOu can download it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `MyLibgdxGame` class misses the source code to display the image, it should look like this:

```
package com.example.mylibgdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class MyLibgdxGame extends Game {
  private OrthographicCamera camera;
  private SpriteBatch        batch;
  private Texture            texture;
  private Sprite             sprite;

  @Override
  public void create() {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h / w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("libgdx2.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth() / 2, -sprite.getHeight() / 2);
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
  }

  @Override
  public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
  }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {
  }

  @Override
  public void pause() {
  }

  @Override
  public void resume() {
  }
}
```

[The guide](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew) suggests to use `gdx-setup-ui.jar` that will generate a complete sample application with this code.

Here is the result:

[image: sample]

Comment: Ohhhh.. i thought the tutorial i follow was a quicktart guide. Thank you sir for this..